# Cambiar icono XAMPP en nueva pagina FPDF

Tags: php, xampp, fpdf

Al general un reporte en mi sistema, utilizando FPDF y abriendo una nueva pestaña con target="_blank", en la barra de navegación aparece el icono de XAMPP y el nombre de la página llamada (reporte.php).
NO pude encontrar en ninguna parte como realizar esto, o sea, que en la barra de navegación, al abrirse la nueva pestaña con el reporte, aparezca el mismo logo y nombre de la empresa que aparece en el resto del sistema, el cual está configurado en el header.php. Si a alguien le paso o sabe como solucionarlo, le agradezco!

Answer (score 0):

¿Has intentado hacer un *require_once* con un *header.php*? Es decir, guardar lo que tienes dentro de la etiqueta `<header></header>` en un archivo aparte, después invocarlo como si fuera un tipo de `conexion.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Si, ya he probado esa opción, pero como FPDF no permite ninguna salida salvo el output del reporte, me da error, el mismo que da por ejemplo, si pones echo "Hola"
Muchas Gracias por responder!

Comment: Estás haciendo un comentario en la zona de respuestas. Si sos quien hizo la pregunta, solicitá [combinar tus perfiles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact).